# cannot get direct urls to work with react router dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

My site is live through github. You cannot get to individual pages by typing out domain/page. However, page will navigate accordingly with navbar at full screen but not at smaller screen with dropdown navbar. [Live Site Here](https://butchered.net/) [github](https://github.com/lhsthree/butchered-react/blob/main/src/containers/header.js)

Comment: site works as should locally

Comment: ya mose of the time local work fine

Comment: may Idea maybe sound weird but can you try to add the exact path to the images
like ./images/Louis.jpg instead of /images/Louis